# AngularJS view not displaying Firebase data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a simple to do list app using AngularJS and Firebase and I am having an issues displaying the data from Firebase to one of my views. I am getting an error in the console and it may be the cause of why the data is not displaying. Here is the error (actually, one is just a warning):

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/assets/js/controllers/taskcontoller.js".
taskcontoller.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:10126 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/ng/areq?p0=TasksController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at Db (http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:19:106)
    at Ya (http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:19:193)
    at http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:67:405
    at link (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/lib/angular-route.min.js:7:248)
    at J (http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:54:373)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:47:256)
    at http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:46:377
    at http://localhost:8000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:48:217
```

Here is the View:

```
<ul class="list col-sm-12 text-center">
    <li ng-repeat="task in activeTasks">
        <div class="item">
            <p>{{task.taskName}}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
myApp.controller('TasksController',
    function($scope, $firebase){
        var activeTasksRef = new Firebase('https://project-name.firebaseio.com/tasks/activeTasks');
        var completedTasksRef = new Firebase('https://project-name.firebaseio.com/tasks/completedTasks');

        var activeTasks = $firebase(activeTasksRef);
        var completedTasks = $firebase(completedTasksRef);

        $scope.activeTasks = activeTasks.$asObject();
        $scope.completedTasks = completedTasks.$asObject();

});
```

And, here is the App.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',
    ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'appControllers', 'ui.bootstrap']);

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', ['firebase']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/active-tasks', {
            templateUrl: '/views/active-tasks.html',
            controller: 'TasksController',
        }).
        when('/completed-tasks', {
            templareUrl: '/views/completed-tasks.html',
            controller: 'TasksController',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/active-tasks'
        });
}]);
```

I do have Angular defined in the html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure why you have a comma after your controller in `controller: 'TasksController'`. There is nothing that comes after it. Try to take them out and see what happens.

Also, why have you created two Firebase databases to separate views? You do not need to do that. You can separate your tasks easily using `$asArray()` instead of `$asObject`. I have done a similar project to the one you're doing now. [You can look at my code if you wish](https://github.com/AbdullahAlger/angular-task-list/blob/master/client/app/home/home.controller.js).

Comment: @A.Alger Thanks for the reply! I managed to get it working. I created another controller and added the code and it worked - still no idea why. As far as your question about different databases, I do not have different databases. It is the same database for al the tasks, I just have the current tasks and archived tasks separated. I am definitely going to look at your code and get some ideas. Thanks for the help!